# ¿Cómo trata PHP los tipos de dato? Una duda entre String e Int

Tags: php, conversión-de-tipos

Tengo una duda,  trabajando en PHP:

Yo recibo desde mi base de datos un valor de una columna del tipo `int` en la siguiente variable y le digo que lo quiero como lo que es, o sea, un entero, usando `(int)`.

```
$nLiturgia = (int) $row["cod_liturgia"];
```

Tengo comprobado que, generalmente, no convertir ese dato a `int` funciona bien, pero tengo una costumbre, heredada de Java, de trabajar los datos con su tipo real, por eso, si ese dato es del tipo `int` en su origen tengo la costumbre o manía o como quieran llamarlo, de convertirlo a su tipo, porque además sospecho que en cualquier escenario podría haber un fallo inesperado.

Hasta ahí todo bien.

Pero resulta que ahora quiero obtener sólo los dos primeros dígitos de mi variable `$nLiturgia`. Para ello recurro a la función `mb_substr`.

```
$nTiempo = (int) mb_substr($nLiturgia, 0, 2);
```

De acuerdo a la documentación de PHP y como el mismo nombre lo indica la función `mb_`**`substr`**`()` trabaja con **cadenas**, por lo que imagino que **re-convierte mi entero a cadena de nuevo**, y yo a mi vez convierto a `int`el `int` que `mb_substr()` ha convertido a cadena.

Entonces tengo dos preguntas:

1. ¿En este caso el tipo de dato no tiene ninguna importancia en PHP?
2. ¿Conocen alguna función que extraiga n cantidad de cifras de un número entero? Algo parecido a `mb_substr()`, una especie de `mb_subint()`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Según la documentación
http://php.net/manual/es/language.types.intro.php

El tipo de una variable usualmente no lo declara el programador; al contrario, es decidido en tiempo de ejecución por PHP dependiendo del contexto en el que se emplea dicha variable.

Una variable puede ser evaluada con valores diferentes en ciertas situaciones, dependiendo del tipo que posea en cada momento.

No obstante se puede amoldar o forzar el tipo.

Los siguientes forzados de tipos están permitidos:

```
(int), (integer) - forzado a integer

(bool), (boolean) - forzado a boolean

(float), (double), (real) - forzado a float

(string) - forzado a string

(array) - forzado a array

(object) - forzado a object

(unset) - forzado a NULL (PHP 5)
```

El forzado de tipo es recomendado en comparaciones estrictas ya que estas comparan también que sean del mismo tipo.

Por ejemplo esto compara si son iguales y del mismo tipo

```
 $a === $b
```

Comment: Respecto a la segunda pregunta cosidero que mejor hacerla en una pregunta aparte, añadiendo un ejemplo de lo esperado.

Answer (score 0):

Hasta donde me lo permite mi conocimiento sobre PHP; a la pregunta 1... el tipo de dato tiene importancia según como lo uses tu. Si quieres emplear el número para una operación matemática este dato debe ser obviamente numérico. Al contrario, si lo utilizas en una cadena, debe ser String.
A la segunda pregunta; puedes ojear la función de PHP intval()
http://php.net/manual/es/function.intval.php
En todo caso, cuando desees ver el tipo de dato, puedes imprimir por pantalla con la función var_dump() que te dice el tipo de dato como lo estas usando después de cierta línea.

Comment: No sé en qué puede ayudar `intval()`, y el truco de mirar el tipo con `var_dump()` no es necesario teniendo [`gettype()`](http://php.net/gettype) que hace justo eso.

Answer (score 0):

1) No se si no tiene ninguna importancia asi tan explicitamente pero al declarar variables no es necesario especificar el tipo de dato como en otros lenguajes, tu deberias poder validar u ocupar tus variables de manera correcta, tal cuando en Java por ejemplo cuando intentas sumar un int y un string (caso raro xD) el compilador te reclama y tienes que hacer la conversión respectiva, asegurarte que esa conversión sea correcta etc etc. Pero si necesitas saber que tipo de dato contiene tu variable puedes utilizar `gettype` te dejo la documentacion [aquí](http://php.net/manual/es/function.gettype.php)

2) para extraer n cantidad de numeros de una cifra puedes utilizar simplemente `echo substr($tu_numero, 0, 2);` donde 2 es la cantidad de cifras que quieres en este caso.